# what is the difference between these 2 mongoose schemas while exporting them?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Below is the schema for one user profile in my project.

```
 var agencyProfile = mongoose.Schema({
      name: {
        type: String
      },
      user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "users"
      }
    })
```

I would like to know what is the difference between these 2 exported schemas?

```
 module.exports = mongoose.model('agencyProfile', agencyProfile);
    vs
module.exports = mongoose.model('agencyProfile', agencyProfile, "agencyProfile");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument basically allows you to change the collection name (which is inferred from the model-name by default) to something else. From the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-model):

> When no collection argument is passed, Mongoose uses the model name.
> If you don't like this behavior, either pass a collection name, use
> mongoose.pluralize(), or set your schemas collection name option.

In your case, it does not make any difference as the collection name matches the model name `agencyProfile`.